# How to bypass security dialog when the JNLP file is run

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp

I have created a Java Web Start application. I have signed my Jar with a self-signed certificate. Also the web-server who serves the Jar and JNLP file is trusted with its certificate.

When the JNLP file is run, it opens following dialog. I wish to know if there is any way to make not to show this dialog and open the application window directly as soon as it is run.

[image: Dialog]

When I googled, I couldn't find any sources referring this issue.

Looking for your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wish to know if there is any way to make not to show this dialog ..

No. If you find a way, it is a security bug. So please let us know - we can have it fixed.

> ..and open the application window directly as soon as it is run.

That is not even possible with a fully certified code signing certificate!

#### Update

The web-start plugin was deprecated from the Java API and removed as of Java 9. A large part of the reason it was removed is that (Sun Microsystems then) Oracle kept reintroducing *security bugs* that had been fixed in earlier versions.

Kind of ironic, given the original question. 'Too much' security was 'never enough' to provide a plug-in that delivered software in a secure manner.

Comment: I've seen the same dialog before with a checkbox saying "Do not show this again for this app from the publisher above". Do you know what causes that checkbox to be visible, and would that one time approval do what the OP is asking for later runs?

Comment: @Manius Those are not apps. that are signed "with a self-signed certificate" as the OP stated. They were apps. signed with a certificate issued by a Certification Authority. It's all changed anyway. 1) About a year ago, Oracle decided they were no longer allowing 'self signed' code to be launched at all. Even with OK'ing a dialog each launch. 2) More recently still, they decided that support for JWS will be dropped in Java 9 (for both self signed, and CA certified code). - It's a dead horse, stop flogging it.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of the self-signed cert bit--fine with it and not arguing that. Some confusion here is coming from the fact that I'm seeing this dialog (without such a checkbox) for an app which is signed by what should be a trusted CA. But elsewhere it does appear with the checkbox. Wasn't aware of that Java 9 part, that's "great"...

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a documented answer to this question either but did find output of javaws -verbose that directed me to the "Internet Explorer certificate store" on a Windows box.

Grabbing the codesigning certificate from the .jar file and putting it into Windows' Trusted Publishers store solved the issue for me. Obviously Windows must then be able to validate the certificate. This does seem to work with in-house PKI though.

Tested only on Windows as the above was sufficient for me (rather than configuring rulesets with all that entails) as it makes deployment that much easier.

Dunno if that's a bug as per @Andrew Thompson's reply, though in my book it is significantly more unsafe to have a user confirm each and every execution if the .jnlp is updated but the referenced (and signed!) .jar is not.

But that's outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

I beg to differ from @Andrew Thompson's anwser above, but [oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/plugin003.html#BABBHCBF) has specified how to avoid these messages.

> Grant AllPermissions in the Java policy file located at
>   ${user.home}/.java.policy, or point to any Java policy file which has
>   AllPermissions in the $(JRE_HOME)/lib/security/java.security file.
>   Permissions can be granted to all applications or restricted to a
>   particular URL. See Default Policy Implementation and Policy File
>   Syntax for more details on .java.policy.